# Can I use CDI to inject a resource into a JAX-RS Application/ResourceConfig?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I'd like for my ResourceConfig to have access to a database for its configuration.  I've tried this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private MyEjb myEjb;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      // em and myEjb are both null
      ...
    }
```

But neither the EntityManager, not the EJB, are injected (both are null)

Is there a special way to do this in JAX-RS?

NOTE: I'm able to inject resources into a Path-annotated class just fine.  I'm having trouble doing it in the actual ApplicationPath-annotated class.

Comment: see the docs for more info: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html

Comment: @WilderValera actually did read that document before, but it only looks like it is for creating resources that can be injected into the web service resources (Path annotated)...it doesn't seem to apply to injecting a resource into the ApplicationPath annotated class, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. When your ApplicationConfig  class is loaded, MyEjb  haven't been injected . Your AbstractBinder needs to run first and be be registered. Does it make sense for you? and , why do you need inject in your ApplicationConfig  class?

Comment: only jax-rs understands this ```ApplicationConfig```. To have non-jaxrs injection into it, you need to enable it for CDI, by annotating it with ```ApplicationScoped```

Comment: @maress I already tried annotating it with ApplicationScoped and that didn't work.

Comment: @WilderValera I want to inject a database resource because I'm trying to use swagger with my web services and swagger requires some configuration variables to be set in its BeanConfig (inside the ResourceConfig).  I'd like to populate those variables with database variables on startup.

Comment: Try to create a class where you can inject your object then call that class after all the register (use AbstractBinder) process in ApplicationConfig. It might work. I haven't had enough time to test it.

Comment: @wsaxton I have the same need. Did you manage to inject your configuration?